# How to control formatting and objects in empty filler space when "Keep Group Together" is used?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report where I am using colored boxes to delineate columns. To accomplish this, I've run the boxes from the Group Header all the way down to the Report Footer. Crystal seems to enjoy making the boxes "bleed" up and down the page so that they seem to print wherever they want in the Header and Footer.

I got the idea to use other solid white boxes to control this and it works, *except* when Crystal adds more filler space when "Keep Group Together" is used. For example, when the next group won't fit so is moved to the next page. This space doesn't belong to any actual Report Section. Unfortunately, if I uncheck "Keep Group Together", I get other formatting problems so that's not an option. Any ideas of how I can get this formatting under control?

[image]

Comment: So in the diagram above, [Whiteout box here] represents a solid white box you've added to prevent Crystal extending your column boxes to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @noa That's right. I've also tried spanning the whiteout box into the Report Footer which worked in whiting out the colored columns at the bottom, but it also whited out the colored columns at the _top_ in GH1 for some reason so I scrapped the idea of using the box at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be to not span the colored columns into the Report Footer section. For some reason, they're fine when spanning groups and details, but as soon as it hits the RF it explodes.

Instead, I just created new colored column boxes and lined them up in the RF separately. It's behaving itself now.

Comment: In the question you said you were spanning to the group footer, but Crystal's odd behavior makes more sense given you were spanning to the report footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking your whiteout box **Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing**.

I'm guessing here: your column boxes are marked **Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing**, and they're getting extended, but your whiteout box is not.

Comment: I tried that, but it really did only extend to the bottom of that GF1 section and left the extra colored columns.

Comment: Oh, also, I tried setting column boxes to "Extend to Bottom..." and I don't recall what happened between them (I tried a bunch of things!) but it didn't solve the problem.